# How to get mongo TTL to expire in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Mongo isn't expiring old collections. I checked to make sure my index is type date.

```
var keys = IndexKeys.Ascending("expiry");
var options = IndexOptions.SetTimeToLive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

collection.EnsureIndex(keys, options);
this.ExpireDate = new BsonDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5));
var insertResult = collection.Insert(this);
```

Any tips would be gladly appreciated.

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "Showsv1.ShowInfo",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "expiry" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "Showsv1.ShowInfo",
            "name" : "expiry_1",
            "expireAfterSeconds" : 60
    }
```

]

```
"expiry" : ISODate("2013-02-15T02:40:45.876Z")
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are not accidentally tripping up on one of the constraints (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).  That should work as long as `"expiry"` is a date time field and there are no other indexes on the field.

Comment: There isn't any index fields beside the expiry

Comment: `ExpireDate` and `expiry`? Those need to match if I understand your code snippet.

Comment: It does, I am mapping the name in c#.

Comment: Hmm. Using `[BsonElement("expiry")]`? Is there anything else to this then? This seems right given what you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was missing [BsonElement("expiry")] on top of the ExpireTime property. 
Thanks @WiredPrairie for the tip.